# VB.Net Convert ToDecimal won´t work with comma

Tags: vb.net, decimal, formatexception

I´m trying to parse a String to a Decimal but I keep getting a formatException

```
Dim row as GridViewRow
    for each row in grdActieRittenActiefAlt.rows
        Dim rbl as RadioButtonList = row.FindControl("tblAddAct")
        'toevoegen = true
        if rbl.SelectedItem.Value = true then
            Dim opgaveIdent as Integer = Convert.ToInt32(grdActieRittenActiefAlt.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value.ToString())

            Dim curOldTarief as Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(lblCuratiefTarief.Text)
            Dim curOldKorting as Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(lblCuratiefKorting.Text)

            Dim curTariefString as String = row.Cells(4).Text
            Dim curKortingString as String = row.Cells(6).Text

            Dim curTarief as Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(curTariefString)
            Dim curKorting as Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(curKortingString)

            lblCuratiefTarief.Text = (curOldTarief + curTarief).ToString()
            lblCuratiefKorting.Text = (curOldKorting + curKorting).ToString()


        end if
    next row
```

The input is 431,25. 
So far I've tried the following:

Changing the comma to a colon using .Replace(",",".") => Didn't work

Using a forced CultureInfo => Didn't work

Use the row.Cells(4).Text directly => Didn't work

Use a substring query to get only the round numbers (431) => Worked but is no solution

Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Comment: What culture is the program running with? Did you try `Decimal.Parse`?

Comment: I can't reproduce your results with the replacement - `Convert.ToDecimal("431,25".Replace(',', '.'))` results in `431.25`. Using `Decimal.Parse` with the culture `fr-FR` works as expected too.

Comment: Decimal.Pase gave the same result. The culture is nl-NL.

Comment: Check your input string. Make sure there are not strange characters around it. If you are importing from Excel/HTML (guess here, based on `row.Cells(4).Text`) you may be getting extra characters.

Comment: I found solution but it's not quit the best one.. The data comes from a datagrid. By changing the boundfield in the grid to a templatefield with a label and using that label to convert the decimal of it works. I have no idea why but it resolved the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a lot more testing and trying I've found a workaround/solution for the problem.

The row.Cells(4).Text was a boundfield. I've changed that to a TemplateField with a label.
By making a local variable (Label) and using that to convert the decimal from it works. I got no idea why but for me it's a solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the FormatNumber function?

```
FormatNumber(number, 2)
```

2 is the number of decimal places.